# Убрать BOM из файла

Tags: c#, файлы, powershell, bom

Есть массив байтов byte[] buffer, я считываю его в строку и преобразую в base64

```
string chunk = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
```

После я передаю ее в powershell-скрипт на С#, где декодирую обратно и записываю в файл эту строку

```
$DataDecoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String('Chunk'))
Invoke-Command {$using:DataDecoded | Add-Content -Path C:\Test\Script1.ps1 -NoNewLine} -ComputerName " + configuration.Ip + @" -Credential $Cred
```

В итоге таких циклов может быть несколько пока копирую файл кусками, и на выходе получаю файл где в самом начале первой строки стоит знак вопроса '?'
Больше нигде нет, если меняю кодировку в строке на ASCII то появляется три знака вопроса '???'

Я так понимаю, это BOM. Мне конечно нужен файл без этих знаков вопроса...возможно как-то его убрать? я уже перепробовал все варианты с этими кодировками

Comment: А почему бы не передать в powershell сразу буфер?..

Comment: @PavelMayorov мне сказали сначала кодировать в base64, а потом декодировать уже в powershell

Comment: А если бы вам сказали с крыши небоскреба спрыгнуть - вы бы прыгнули?

Comment: Если бы вы привели задачу полностью, то правильный ответ был бы получен ещё вчера (в предыдущем вопросе). Что работаете с текстом, что читаете блоками... и т. п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BOM (byte order mark) существует в файле. Вот и нужно решать проблему при чтении из файла!

Наверняка вы читаете массив байтов из файла следующим образом:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

Естественно, если в файле присутствует BOM, то эти байты попадают в массив.

Поэтому прочитайте данные из файла именно как текст, при этом BOM будет устранена. Далее из текста получите байты в нужной кодировке.

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(path);
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
```

Comment: Мне нужно читать данные из файла частями (1кб), поэтому считываю в массив байтов

Comment: @Алексей - Насколько я могу судить по вашим вопросам, вы читаете из _текстового_ файла. Так? Уточните (отредактируйте вопрос). Если да, то **нельзя** работать с текстом как с байтами. Читая по килобайту, вы рискуете разорвать многобайтовый символ посередине. Поэтому читайте с помощью `StreamReader` блоки _текста_ (_не байтов_!). Проблемы с BOM при этом не возникнет.

Comment: у меня файл будет скрипт powershell.ps1 
я читаю его через FileStream

Comment: @Алексей - Скрипт - это текстовый файл. `FileStream` читает _байты_. Это неправильно! В многобайтовых кодировках (например, UTF8) одни символ (буква) может быть закодирован несколькими байтами. Например, с номерами 1023, 1024, 1025. Читая ровно один килобайт (1024 байта), вы прочтёте _часть_ этого символа, разорвёте его.

Comment: Допустим, но у меня задача прочитать полностью файл, я считываю кусок, вставляю в другой файл, считываю другой кусок, вставляю опять в другой файл, и символы в конце-концов станут опять вместе если я разорвал их. Я тестировал читал большой файл разными кусками (от 100 до 1024б) и все нормально в итоге получалось в конечном файле

Comment: @Алексей - Да, при таком сценарии символы в итоге вернутся на место, станут правильными. Но в общем - нельзя работать с текстом, как с байтами. И BOM - лишь одна из причин. Просто замените `FileStream` на `StreamReader`. И вместо массива байтов читайте массив чаров (char).

Comment: Я Вас понял, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
if (String1.StartsWith(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble()), StringComparison.Ordinal)) {
   String2 = String1.Remove(0, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble()).Length);
}
```

Можно в лоб, по проще:

```
String1.Trim(new char[]{'\uFEFF'});
```

или так чтоб ещё убрать пробел между BOM и текстом:

```
String1.Trim(new char[]{'\uFEFF','\u200B'});
```

Comment: Лучше еще .trimstart(), чтобы в конце не убивать такое.

Answer (score 0):

Я удалил символы отвечающие за BOM, только уже с base64 конвертированной строки. У меня получилось вот так:

```
fileChunk = fileChunk.Replace("77u/", "");
```